# Storing a pointer to T in a void* but T may be const or nonconst - use void const* or just void*?

Tags: c++, constants, void-pointers, type-erasure

When template code needs to store a `T*` in a variable of type `void*` so that it can be retrieved and cast back to a `T*` later, but it needs to handle both `T` and `T const*`, should it use `void*` or a `void const*` for the type erased storage?  (Either choice requires at least one const cast somewhere.)

(Assume that the program tracks at runtime what was put into the void* to ensure it only retrieves the same type as what was put in, but it doesn't know at compile time what type is going to be stored in the variable.)

Edit:  Also assume that the un-typed storage is hidden behind a wrapper class that has templated set() and get() methods, which record what T was used for the set() call and throw an exception if a different T is used for the get().  So the question is really about how should the wrapper class store it.  (Note: the wrapper class is not itself a template; just its methods set() and get() are templates.)

In the past, I've used a `union { void* p_nc; void const* p_c; };` when this problem came up.  However I'm wondering if that's overkill compared to just using a const_cast.

The question is, which way is better (if any):  cast the const off `T const*` upon storage in a `void*`, or use a `void* const` for storage and cast the const off if retreiving a nonconst `T*`?

Comment: Any reason not to just store both pointers and leave the non-const pointer set to nullptr when a const pointer is used? That seems like the obvious way to do it, at least to me.

Comment: David - I thought about that too, and almost added it to the question.  Then I realized it's functionally equivalent to the "union" case, just differing in how its storage is laid out.

Comment: It's not quite because it doesn't require a separate check to see which pointer is valid. (When you set a non-const pointer, you set both pointers.)

Comment: Right but the thing is the code has to know what type it's casting to anyway on the get() function, so it already knows if it's const.  This would be a separate variable that stores what type was in the pointer.  It could be something derived from RTTI type_id, or an enumeration value, etc.

Comment: Leaving aside "const", the storage is "void*" and the actual-type is "T*".  When the pointer is stored the type "T" is lost.  When the stored value is retrieved it has type "void*" and has to be cast back to "T*".  Supposing for example we are talking about storing an "int", T could just as easily be made to "int const" as "int".  So if we know "T" at retrieval we also know whether it is "int" or "int const".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the point of view of somebody who is going to read your code (even you in the future, 6 months from now) it is better to express the idea as clearly as possible instead of trying to minimize the number of times you cast.

In your case using a `union` says "it can be either one" but it doesn't put any checks on actually enforcing its usage.

OTOH having a clear interface that implements both const and non-const access functions (including cast functions) allows you to perform runtime-check and act accordingly (error message? exception?).

A clear interface has an added benefit of encapsulating the implementation so that your client code doesn't depend on the internal structure of the implementation - your client code will just use your template as const or non-const (depending on the usage) and the access/cast functions will take care of making sure the usage is actually valid.

Comment: Thanks, but I was rather assuming an interface hiding the storage exists, and asking about how should the implementation of that interface handle storing the pointers.I omitted describing the method of ensuring correct type access because I didn't want to make the question too long.  It could be that the add() assigns a unique ID to each T, or it could be that there are a small enough number of types to use an enumeration variable.